# How do i make an exception when clearing a c# form?

Tags: c#, controls

I need to clear a form of my application. But there are 2 controls that I don't want it to clear.

When I click on another option in my `ComboBox`. It first wipes all controls and then loads the new controls in. (Or atleast that's what I'm trying to achieve.)

This code loops through all controls within the form and checks whether the control names do not equal to `cmbType` or `lblType`. (Because this way it will leave those 2 controls untouched when clearing all controls.)

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.Name != "cmbType" && c.Name != "lblType")
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(c);
        c.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But this way it will sometimes when I click different options in my `ComboBox` it will not remove all controls completely. It will leave some controls which is not suppose to happen.

Comment: Your method of doing this does not account for child controls within controls such as panels or group boxes.

Comment: The loop and loop source are working in the middle of the reverse. You are subtracting from the source you are targeting.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne We don't use any panels. This is only in a form. and not in a panel.

Comment: Use `foreach (Control c in this.Controls.ToList())`, to solve the problem mentioned by @snnbm

Comment: @snnbrn I don't really understand your comment. Could you please be more clear?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't have the option to use: ToList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for to list

```
 foreach (Control item in Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you care to explain a little bit, where did we go wrong?